How to attach an existing EBS volume to EC2 in CDK
I am creating an EC2 instance in CDK(TypeScript).
const webServer = new ec2.Instance(this, 'web-server', {
  vpc: vpc,
  // other properties
  blockDevices: [
    {
      deviceName: "/dev/sdb1",
      volume: ec2.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(10)
    }
  ]
});

This creates a new EBS volume.
How do I attach an existing EBS volume to this EC2.

This question is similar to: How to attach an EC2 volume to an EC2 instance using AWS CDK. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
